# How to Create Mouseover event programmatically in asp.net GridView

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datagridview

I have a mouseover in my Grid in one of the columns ID where I am calling one

> function myHandler(event)

but I have some columns which I am creating dynamically based on condition like NameField where based
on condition Hyperlink and label is coming but there is no such mouseover event .
How to create a mouse over event in my NameField and calls the same mouseover function?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" onmouseover = "mouseover(event)"></asp:Label>
```

Mouseover function

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function mouseover(event) {
//doing something
} </script>
```

Code behind:

```
private static System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField NameField()
{
    if(name=="hyperlink")
    {
        return new HyperLinkField
        {
            HeaderText = "EmployeeName",
            DataTextField = "Name",
            SortExpression = "Name",  
        };
    }
    else
    {
        return new LabelField
               {
                   HeaderText = "EmployeeName",
                   DataTextField = "Name",
                   SortExpression = "Name",
               };
}
```

Comment: What is `LabelField`? Is it some kind of custom grid view field you have defined?

Comment: Yes Andrei this one is customizable field i can give mouseover event in ascx control but when i am trying to give in cs it is not working

Comment: Can you show how is it defined? The idea is that you need to setup the attribute of the underlying label control, but I cannot advise exactly how unless I see how LabelField is implemented